# maximum of derivatives of lipschitz functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, integration, optimization

Say $f$, and $g$ are nondecreasing functions on [a,b], differentiable with derivatives bounded by 1. can one infer that

$$\int_a^b \min\left(\frac{d}{dx} f(x),\frac{d}{dx} g(x)\right)\,dx \leq \int_a^b \min\left(\frac{d}{dx} v(x),\frac{d}{dx} h(x)\right)\,dx$$

if $f\leq v$ and $g\leq h$ and otherwise $v$, $h$ have the same properties as $f$, $g$? Maybe there is a way to drag the differential out, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, let $[a,b]=[0,1]$, $f(x)=g(x)=x$, and $v(x)=h(x)=1$. Then the left side is $1$ and the right side is $0$.

If this seems like cheating, we can do something similar even under the constraints that $f, g, v,$ and $h$ must have the same values at $a$ and $b$. For example, $[a,b]=[0,1]$, $f(x)=g(x)=v(x)=x/2$, and $h(x)=\frac12-\frac12(1-x)^2$.